# Template specialization works with g++ but not with Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have a bunch of templated code that compiles fine under g++, but now when I try to build under windows with Visual C++ 2010 I get a bunch of errors.

I have a collection of template functions for getting and setting values in C++ objects from Lua code. For example, I have this template:

```c
//        Class       Return type Getter function
template <typename T, typename U, U (T::*Getter)() const>
int luaU_get(lua_State* L)
{
    T* obj = luaW_check<T>(L, 1); // Gets userdata from stack and checks if it's of type T
    luaU_push(L, (obj->*Getter)()); // Runs the getter function specified in the template, and pushes the
    return 1;
}
```

(The complete file can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper/src/2728f5bfb5eb/LuaWrapperUtil.hpp))

Which is instantiated here:

```c
static luaL_reg TextArea_MT[] =
{
    //                             Class     Return type   Getter function
    { "GetCharacterSize", luaU_get<TextArea, unsigned int, &TextArea::GetCharacterSize> },
    { NULL, NULL }
};
```

The signature for that getter is as follows:

```
unsigned int GetCharacterSize() const;
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors like this:

```
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const' to 'unsigned int *(__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* const )(void) const'
2>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2973: 'luaU_get' : invalid template argument 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const'
2>          C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\extern\LuaWrapper\LuaWrapperUtil.hpp(147) : see declaration of 'luaU_get'
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const' to 'unsigned int *ag::ui::TextArea::* const '
2>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2973: 'luaU_get' : invalid template argument 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const'
2>          C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\extern\LuaWrapper\LuaWrapperUtil.hpp(131) : see declaration of 'luaU_get'
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const' to 'unsigned int ag::ui::TextArea::* const '
2>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2973: 'luaU_get' : invalid template argument 'unsigned int (__thiscall ag::ui::TextArea::* )(void) const'
2>          C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\extern\LuaWrapper\LuaWrapperUtil.hpp(123) : see declaration of 'luaU_get'
2>C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\game\dev\src\game\lua\LuaTextArea.cpp(103): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'lua_CFunction'
2>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

Comment: What is the actual signature of `TextArea::GetCharacterSize`?

Comment: Updated the question with the signature of `GetCharacterSize`

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me -- the overload on line 139 should be called, but instead the overload on line 147 is being called.

Comment: Also, terminology nitpick -- one cannot specialize function templates, this is merely overloading.

Comment: I thought that was the case. I only mentioned specialization because the error messages did.

Comment: @ildjarn i'm sorry but the nitpick is mistaken. you *can* specialize function templates.

Comment: @Johannes : Please correct my memory then. :-] Is it only that they cannot be _partially_ specialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compiler bug in VC++. The following code is valid:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TextArea
{
    unsigned GetCharacterSize() const { return 0; }
};

template<typename T, typename U, U (T::*)() const>
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}

template<typename T, typename U, U* (T::*)() const>
int foo()
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<TextArea, unsigned, &TextArea::GetCharacterSize>() << '\n';
}
```

And compiles with [GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/ivlpe), [GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/Q3ISh), and Comeau 4.3.10.1 Beta2 (no link), but yields the following error with VC++ 2010 SP1:

> error C2668: `'foo'` : ambiguous call to overloaded function

---

**EDIT:** As for a workaround, it's ugly, but the only thing I can think of offhand is to use an extra layer of indirection so that there is no overloading involved:

```
#include <iostream>

struct WithPointer
{
    unsigned* GetCharacterSize() const { return nullptr; }
};

struct WithoutPointer
{
    unsigned GetCharacterSize() const { return 0u; }
};

template<bool UsePointerImplB>
struct kludge
{
    template<typename T, typename U, U (T::*Getter)() const>
    static int foo() { return 1; }
};

template<>
struct kludge<true>
{
    template<typename T, typename U, U* (T::*Getter)() const>
    static int foo() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << kludge<false>::foo<WithoutPointer, unsigned, &WithoutPointer::GetCharacterSize>() << '\n'
        << kludge<true>::foo<WithPointer, unsigned, &WithPointer::GetCharacterSize>() << '\n';
}
```

Effectively this is no different than just giving each overload a different name...

Comment: If it's a known and demonstrable bug, has anyone filed it with MS?

Comment: @CodyGray, I have not, but I don't know where to submit bugs like this, or how to check if its a known issue.

Comment: @Alex : Search for existing bugs and post new bugs at [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/). Once you've found or submitted the relevant bug, please post a link back here so we can vote it up. :-]

Answer (score 1):

If you can force user to pick the actual return type of the function, the following works. Maybe, it'll be useful to you:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FooBar
{
  int Foo( void ) const
  {
   std::cout << "FooBar::Foo()" << std::endl;
   return ( 0 );
  }
  int * Bar( void ) const
  {
   std::cout << "FooBar::Bar()" << std::endl;
   return ( 0 );
  }
};

template< typename P00, typename P01, P01(P00::*p02)( void ) const >
void Call()
{
 P00 lT;
 ( lT.*p02 )();
}

int main( void )
{
 Call< FooBar, int, &FooBar::Foo > ();
 Call< FooBar, int*, &FooBar::Bar > ();

 return( 0 );
}
```

Program output:

```
FooBar::Foo()
FooBar::Bar()
```